# What is the effect of class="something" in a link on SEO

Tags: seo, html, hyperlink

I'm wondering what the effect would be of a class in the HTML.

Say I have a script that tracks events that I can turn off by adding class="notracking" to the link. Would this effect the SEO effect of a (dofollow) link?

This is how the HTML would look like:

```
<a class="notracking" href="http://www.example.com/" target="_blank">Exaple linktext</a>
```

Comment: 1. No 2. There is no such thing as dofollow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No relation to SEO what so ever,  classes and id's are on-site attributes for styling and/or scripting.

You should also note there is no such thing as "dofollow",   by default SE's will crawl,  unless told otherwise with "nofollow" and "noindex" attributes

Comment: "there is no such thing as "dofollow"" - _dofollow_ is simply an _expression_, when you need to express that a link is _not a "nofollow"_ (avoids the double negative).

Comment: Its a pointless "expression".   No one should assume its "nofollow" unless otherwise stated.  The more people keep expressing it as a "thing", the more its adding to the misconception that they should use it.  You only have to search for how many sites actually use the attribute to see that sometimes, people are not clever enough to judge whether something is an expression or an factual statement.

Comment: Google has been known to render pages and compare the output with the mark-up - if you are using classes to visually hide links that can be a problem and you can be penalised for it. While clearly not the intent in this case, it should be noted for the otherwise sweeping statement that classes are not important.